# React Native useEffect and useState showing previous state on controlled TextInput

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state, react-hooks

I am getting a very strange issue with React Native useState and useEffect and I can't work it out. I've got a simple form but have striped down all the components to one `TextInput`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { TextInput } from 'react-native'

const InputExample = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('')


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('1:', name)
    console.log('2:', name)
  }, [name])

  return (
    <TextInput
      placeholder="First name"
      maxLength={100}
      value={name}
      onChangeText={(text) => setName(text)}
      style={{ margin: 20, fontSize: 20, borderColor: 'black', borderWidth: 1, padding: 10 }}
    />
  )
}

export default InputExample
```

How `useEffect` should work in my opinion here is printing the current state each time e.g.

```
// First Render - Text Input 'P'
1: {firstName: "P"}
2: {firstName: "P"}

// Second Render - Text Input 'Pe'
1: {firstName: "Pe"}
2: {firstName: "Pe"}

etc..
```

But what I get is

```
// First Render - Text Input 'P'
1: {firstName: "P"}

// Second Render - Text Input 'Pe'
2: {firstName: "P"}
1: {firstName: "Pe"}
```

So I'm getting a mixture of states (previous and old)

Comment: `setState` functions are async and react internally could/will batch state updates

Comment: How is this a mix of states? It's still 2 Ps and then Pe. You've just added an empty line between them.

Comment: @Dane I've updated the question to hopefully make it clearer

Comment: So you're saying after first render, only one of two console logs were printed?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I'll put first render - second render

Comment: the first console log of the second render is labeled 2. That along with its value tells me its actually coming from the first useEffect call, not stale data from the second

Comment: Copying this code into a codepen logs what you expect. I think something else is going on. All I did was swap native for regular react. I guess that could change things, but I wouldn't think so

Answer (score -1):

per the behavior you had,  it looks like you return the second console.log as cleanup function in the useEffect. it's very odd if you didn't.

that's why I said add a semicolon at end. It's possible useEffect implictly return your second console.log as a cleanup function, because you don't have a semicolon at end of your 1st console.log? I'm just guessing.